# WPF: Relations between multiple Entities

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4

I am working in a WPF application where I save data to multiple databases. Let's say that I have Database A and B. For every database A there should be database B.  If you create a new instance of A, a new instance of B should be created too. In my application A and B are separat. How can I make a new database of B created whenever A database is created?

Comment: You're creating databases every save? Perhaps you mean "every time a *record* is saved to A, a (similar? duplicate?) record is saved to B"?

Comment: Sorry for not giving too much details. What I mean is that I have a database called Schools and another database called logs. For every new school I create there should be a new log database. So each school has it's own log database.

Comment: You using EF code first to create a database at run time? [According to MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5e1e545-163d-4c97-aaab-a5f9ce6f58f7/multiple-database-support-with-ef-and-code-first) it does not support multiple databases.

Comment: Thank you @sq33G I guess it can't be done from EF.